# What is purpose of the Controllers folder in Layouts?

Tags: presentation, mvc, controller

I've noticed that in `/sitecore/layout` there is a `Controllers` folder (first item underneath actually). In that folder you can add items of type `Controller`. These items have fields for a controller name and action name, so they seem to map to some mvc code.

I did check the links of the template and noticed one usage (`/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules/MVC Controllers`) but this rule is for setting insert options on the folders in the Controllers section in Layouts.

So, my question is: what is the purpose of these items? How could I use them? And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's just another way of creating Controller rendering, You basically create Controller item (Of template ***/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Controller***) and enter the `Controller Name` (***YourNamespace.ControllerClassName***) and `Controller Action` (default is index if blank), Then when you create your controller rendering item you enter the Controller item name that you created previously in **Controller** field, and you leave **Controller Action** field empty.

It does not really give you that much of a benefit unless you think it helps to separate all of your controller definitions in that Controllers folder, and then reference it from the controller renderings in renderings folder

Comment: I agree. I've been thinking about the reasoning - to answer the "why" part of the question. I think this way of setting it up makes sense, if you have a "bundle" of action methods on one controller - for a series of variations of a simple rendering. Like e.g. on a CarouselController, which then would have index methods for VideoSlide, ImageSlide, HeroSlide and so on. By mapping it to a common "Controller" like this - you would only have 1 place in your solution to go and change, if the namespacing/assembly changed - as opposed to editing 6 controller rendering items.

Comment: I left a comment on [this previous post](https://pratiksatikunvar.wordpress.com/2017/07/31/different-way-of-controller-rendering-in-sitecore-differences-doubts/), there are too many things missing from the template that it doesn't fit with the Sitecore way of doing things - Parameters template, Datasource Location, Template, Compatible Renderings, Caching etc. so I don't believe it is a different way of Controller Renderings. Might make slightly more sense as a pointer to a controller....

Comment: @jammykam don't you still have to create controller rendering anyway? Where you can apply parameter template, data source etc ....

Comment: Re-reading this and the other comment, seems like it and I may have misunderstood. Seems a little pointless... kinda like creating the model definition just to select it on your rendering item... solves the mystery at least!

Comment: I can't find any source material to confirm this. But @mdresser blogged about it here: http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/sitecore-mvc-presentation-concepts